# Login to ASP.Net application from Xamarin using Authentication token

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to login to my ASP.net application from xamarin using authentication token.
Here is my **LoginViewModel.cs**

```
public class LoginViewModel : ContentPage
{
    private ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async() =>
            {

                var isLogin = await _apiServices.LoginAsync(Username, Password);

                if (isLogin)
                {
                    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Dashboard());
                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

The var **isLogin** is returning true but the application is not navigating to Dashboard page

Here is my **LoginAsync** function

```
    public async Task<bool> LoginAsync(string userName, string password)
    {
        var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username",userName),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type","password"),

        };

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://epolleasy.azurewebsites.net/Token");

        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        var jwt = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jwt);

        var accessToken = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("access_token"); //variable for acsess_token

        //Debug.WriteLine(jwt);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        {
            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
        else
        {
            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Are you actually getting and storing the token?

Comment: Check I have updated LoginAsync function in which I am getting and storing token. The condition is if it get token, store it in variable. If successful return true. I am getting true but it is not navigating to dashboard page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of the code you have, the problem looks like a simple misunderstanding of how things work.

First it appears you are trying to implement your own MVVM pattern which is fine, except ViewModels aren't pages. Your code shows that you are trying to make your ViewModel a ContentPage. My only guess is that it's so you can access things like Navigation, Alerts and ActionSheets.

If you're implementing your own basic MVVM it may be necessary to make some sacrifices to make things work. In Xamarin Forms, things like Navigation in particular generally requires an understanding of where you want to navigate from. As a basic sample consider the follow where we want to navigate from ViewA to ViewB

**ViewAViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewAViewModel
{
    private Page _page { get; }

    public ViewAViewModel(Page page)
    {
        _page = page;
        NavigateCommand = new Command(OnNavigateCommandExecuted);
    }

    public Command NavigateCommand { get; }

    private void OnNavigateCommandExecuted() =>
        _page.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ViewB());
}
```

You'll notice that my ViewModel in this case accepts a Page so that it can properly navigate from the Page the ViewModel is used on. Because this is such a basic example and everything is set in the constructor, you'll notice this ViewModel doesn't need to inherit from any other class, nor does it even implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Your ViewModels in a real application would likely need to at least implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**ViewA.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BasicMvvm.Views.ViewA">

    <Button Text="Navigate" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" />

</ContentPage>
```

**ViewA.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ViewA : ContentPage
{
    public ViewA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ViewAViewModel(this);
    }
}
```

Now that said you really are better off using an actual MVVM framework. I would suggest that you take a look at [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism) as it will nicely abstract everything away and keep your code nice and testable.

Comment: My login button also bind with loginCommand, How can I bind it with Navigate command at the same time?

Comment: It seems like you need to learn more about MVVM. Try watching this [Introduction to MVVM](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Introduction-to-MVVM) from the Xamarin Show. The code provided is merely meant as a basic example of how it works and how you can make your navigation work. Your actual code doesn't need something called `NavigateCommand`. You might also want to ready an article I wrote on using [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://dansiegel.net/post/2017/03/16/writing-cleaner-more-concise-code-with-fody), which will help you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.